# Gradient Descent diverges when input data changes

Tags: optimization, linear-model, gradient-descent

I'm trying to use the gradient descent to solve the following min problem:

$$\min_R \sum_{j=m}^K|| X_j - RX_{j-i}||_2^2, X\in R^{n \times K}$$ For simplicity, assume $m=i+1,\text{ and } i = 1$. That is I am trying to predict $X_j$ based on the previous point, $X_{j-1}$. The derivative that I derived is:

$$ \sum_{j=m}^K (-X_j +RX_{j-i})X_j^T$$

Then I applied the following gradient descent:

```
R_i = np.random.uniform(-1 / R_i.shape[0], 1 / R_i.shape[1], size=R_i.shape)

for _ in range(0, max_iteration):
    g = gradient(X, R_i, m, K)
    if (np.sum(abs(g))) < 1e-8:
        break
    R_i = R_i - .01 * g

def gradient(X, R_i, m, K):
    sum = 0
    for j in range(m, K):
        sum = sum + np.matmul(np.expand_dims(-X[:, j] + np.matmul(R_i, X[:, j - i]), axis=1),
                              np.expand_dims(X[:, j - i], axis=0))
    return sum
```

I noticed a weird behavior when the input changes from $X$ being:

[image]

to:

[image]

Where in the second case, the `g` diverges to infinity and in the first case `g` goes to zero as expected.

Also, in the first case, the norm difference between the estimated $R$ and $R$ obtained by the analytical solution which is given by setting up the derivative with respect to $R$ to zero:

$$R = (-\sum X_j X_{j-i}^T)^{-1}(\sum X_{j-i}X_{j-i}^T)$$
is about 12. In other words, the solution is not "very close" to the analytical solution.

What am I missing here?

Edit: I used tensorflow as another implementation to my analysis and the problem was solved. I believe the problem is in my implementation but I can't capture. This question should have been posted in stackoverflow I think.

Comment: Try decreasing the step size. It should be less than 1/L where L is the lipschitz constant of the gradient